# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when trying SOAP call

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect to and authenticate with a webservice using SOAP / wsdl, but I constantly get the error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in /path/install.php:16
```

Below is my current code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 

$userinfo = array(
    'Username'=>'test',
    'Password'=>'test'
);

$wsdl_url = 'https://ws-e-distribution.kmd.dk/standard/ServiceAutorisation/ServiceAutorisation.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url);

print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());

//This is the problematic line:
$response = $client->__soapCall('LogOn', array('LogOn' => $userinfo));

var_dump($response);
```

I have tried every possible way of wrapping the username and password parameters that I could conceive of or find anyone suggesting:

- using a custom class
- using a `stdClass`
- using `SoapVar`
- using `SoapParam`
- using a simple array
- double wrapped array
- A lot of combinations of the above.

And I've tried calling the function like `$client->__soapCall('LogOn', [milliontries])` as well as `$client->LogOn([milliontries])`

...nothing works, please help.

Update:

I finally managed to get a different error (that suggests at least I hit upon something slightly less wrong). My code now looks like this:

```
$response = $client->LogOn(array('logon' => array('Username' => 'test','Password' => 'test')));
```

Which gives me an error about the `LogOnType` being unsupported (in Danish, which suggests to me that at least I have some sort of connection to the server now). The username and password array has no effect, I can substitute an empty string and get the same result, the thing that makes the difference is the lowercase `logon`.

If anyone can set up a working example that gives the error `incorrect username or password` I will be forever grateful... but **any** pointers will be much appreciated.

As far as I understand the wsdl gives all the information needed to do this, I'm just too much of a `[your_pick]` to get it...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unbelievable ! It only took nine hours to write these 16 lines of code.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 

$userinfo = array(
    'Username'=>'test',
    'Password'=>'test'
);

$wsdl_url = 'https://ws-e-distribution.kmd.dk/standard/ServiceAutorisation/ServiceAutorisation.svc?wsdl';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl_url, array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));

print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());

//This actually works ! :) :) :)
$response = $client->LogOn(array('logon' => new SoapVar($userinfo, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'LogOnUsername', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebServiceAutorisation.BL')));

var_dump($response);
```

I was *so close* several times, and it turned out the namespace (the URL) was the magic bit I was missing. I had been using the namespace from the main wsdl (or no namespace at all) in every attempt at using `SoapVar`'s.

Well now, on to the actual purpose of logging in, probably won't be any easier