# Why do I get this error "falseObject reference not set to an instance of an object." when I call an operation in my webservice

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a web service and I am calling one of its operations using SOAP client in PHP but all I get is this `["any"]=> string(120) "falseObject reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I want to know is there anything wrong in my code because I belive that my connection to the web service is %100 working.

Is there anything wrong in the xml string that I am creating ?

The operation is :

```
<wsdl:operation name="XmlIslet">
    <wsdl:input message="tns:XmlIsletSoapIn"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:XmlIsletSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

and the description of its parameters in the WSDL is :

```
<wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
        <s:element name="XmlIslet">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlIslem">
                        <s:complexType>
                            <s:sequence>
                                <s:any/>
                            </s:sequence>
                        </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="xmlYetki">
                        <s:complexType>
                            <s:sequence>
                                <s:any/>
                            </s:sequence>
                        </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
        <s:element name="XmlIsletResponse">
            <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="XmlIsletResult">
                        <s:complexType mixed="true">
                            <s:sequence>
                                <s:any/>
                            </s:sequence>
                        </s:complexType>
                    </s:element>
                </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:element>
    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

My soap and PHP code is the following :

```
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$xmlString = "<Firmalar></Firmalar>";

function strtoXmldocument($str)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $str1 = $str;
    return $dom->loadXML($str1);
}

function stringToDataset($xmlString, $username, $password)     
{                       
    $client = new SoapClient('http://1.1.1.1/WSTEST/Service.asmx?WSDL');

    $response = $client->XmlIslet(strtoXmldocument($xmlString)->documentElement,  
strtoXmldocument("<Kullanici><Adi>" .$username. "</Adi><Sifre>" .$password. "</Sifre></Kullanici>")->documentElement);

var_dump($response);
}

stringToDataset($xmlString, $username, $password);
?>
```

The SOAP request is as the following:

```
POST /WSTEST/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <XmlIslet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xmlIslem>xml</xmlIslem>
      <xmlYetki>xml</xmlYetki>
    </XmlIslet>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The SOAP response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <XmlIsletResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <XmlIsletResult>xml</XmlIsletResult>
    </XmlIsletResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

`vardump` output is :

```
usernamepasswordobject(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["XmlIsletResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["any"]=> string(120) "falseObject reference not set to an instance of an object." } }
```

**EDIT :** 
I tried to get the request xml using `htmlentities($client->__getLastRequest())` which shows me an empty body of my request :

```
========= REQUEST ========== 
string(292) 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:XmlIslet>
<ns1:xmlIslem/>
<ns1:xmlYetki/>
</ns1:XmlIslet>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope> "
```

Comment: maybe the object doesnt exist

Comment: use <faultcode> in xml to check if xml was incorrectly formed

Comment: since response has 200 it means everything is proper but u r reading a property for object that is null

Comment: @Rico which object? I check the connection it is working and not throwing any error and then I call the  operation  `$client->XmlIslet`

Comment: @Rico I used this `if (is_soap_fault($response)) {
    trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$response->faultcode}, faultstring: {$response->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);`

and it does not throw any error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574716/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-when-trying-soap-call?rq=1

Comment: @Rico Actually I tried `SoapVar` but it still gives the same error message, Do you think I am passing the xml parameters in the right format? and by the way what is the meaning of `<s:any/>` in the WSDL mentioned inside the parameters

Comment: wow u set a bounty, can u tell me what the request xml looks like, so i can make one for you

Comment: in xml <any> tag is used for adding something which is not defined already. like https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_any.asp the person is defined with firstname and lastname but then it has a any tag so u can add any other thing to person when you use it elsewhere like they added <children>

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php this will print the xml that u sent

Comment: Hi @Basel. Can you provide URL to WSDL definition?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely communicating with a .NET service. This error message is basically a "variable undefined" message.

The WSDL file says, you request must contain two entities: xmlIslem and xmlYetki. But their internal structure is not properly defined, it can be "any"-thing. This, however, doesn't mean, that the remove web service doesn't expect you to provide some data. It looks like you need to pass some data, which you don't, hence the error.

I would contact the web service provider and requested the documentation or specific request examples.

Comment: what does this line do strtoXmldocument("<Kullanici><Adi>" .$username. "</Adi><Sifre>" .$password. "</Sifre></Kullanici>")->documentElement); o.O

Comment: @Rico it is supposed to parse an XMLstring to a XMLDOM Obj, however while it has invalid XML it wont work, it supposed to have the  `<?xml...` header for staters